# Laravel Breadcrumbs for Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, breadcrumbs

I want to install https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs
on Laravel 5.4.

The link above is for Laravel 5.5. (package version 4.x)

So I go to https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/tree/3.x for package version 3.x but I can see that it recommends to install package the same way as it's installed for L 5.5. via:

```
composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs
```

when I run this, I got a mistake:
[image]

Anybody can help me on how to install it's version 3.x?

Thanks in advance!

UPD: I see the package's author also created a separate for for 3.x version here:
https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-breadcrumbs but I still don't understand how to install it for Laravel 5.4....

Comment: Also you can use php code to generate dynamic breadcrumb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966729/laravel-dynamic-breadcrumbs-with-links)

Answer (score 2):

So figured it out myself. You need just run this command:

```
composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs:3.*
```

and it will install https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/tree/3.x

Hope it helps someone:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are using other versions, just read carefully table below, and follow the link according to your Laravel **version**

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Laravel Breadcrumbs</th>
<th>Laravel</th>
<th>PHP</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>5.x</strong></td>
<td>5.6</td>
<td>7.1+</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/tree/4.x">4.x</a></td>
<td>5.5</td>
<td>7.0+</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/tree/3.x">3.x</a></td>
<td>5.0 – 5.4</td>
<td>5.4+</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/tree/2.x">2.x</a></td>
<td>4.0 – 4.2</td>
<td>5.3+</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```