# breadcrumb hiding link in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, breadcrumbs

I want to remove the links in breadcrumbs how do I do that? Currently using this package to do it, davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs.

Is it possible to remove the links?

```
For now I have something like this:
// Summary
Breadcrumbs::register('summary', function ($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('List of Applicant', route('summary'));
});


// Summary > User Information
Breadcrumbs::register('user.show', function ($breadcrumbs,$id) {
    $breadcrumbs->parent('summary', route('summary'));
    $breadcrumbs->push('User Information', route('user.show', $id));
});
```

So I want to remove the link part for Summary when I am in the page of User Information, how do I do that? Example just plain text, Summary > User Information

Comment: did you tried to leave the url in blank?

Comment: What do you mean by leaving the url in blank? Do you mean inside the blade, remove the breadcrumb?

Comment: I mean `$breadcrumbs->push('List of Applicant', '');`

Comment: Oh yes, that was what I wanted, thank you so much I actually tried doing something like yours just now but I took out the wrong part. So sorry for the dumb question here

Comment: Also you can use php code to generate dynamic breadcrumb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966729/laravel-dynamic-breadcrumbs-with-links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `push()` only mandatory param is `title`, so if you want to remove URL from a breadcrumb you can do like this:

*$breadcrumbs->push('User Information');*